# How to fetch a user Facebook photo albums that I am not friends with

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I want to create a FB app that fetches all of Andy's photo albums.  Andy's photo albums are all set to be publicly viewable.  Andy has 0 facebook friends.

With respect to FB permissions... How can I get all of Andy's photo albums to be fetched and displayed onto a public website?  Visitors arriving to the website will NOT be friends with Andy ...and... will NOT do a facebook authentication upon arriving to the site.

Is this feasible? Is it possible to get ALL public photo albums from Andy without requiring permissions or being friends of Andy?

Is one possible solution to... have Andy to provide photo permissions and then do a cron job and store the FB response into a database for the website to fetch from?

Please let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you can't fetch the albums/photos of a non-friend (even if some pictures of that user are public). This is not supported via the API.

You can just get the-

1. photos of the user : `/me/photos` with permission: `user_photos`
2. photos of the friends: `/FRIEND_ID/photos` with permission: `friends_photos`
3. current profile picture of any user xyz: `/USER_ID/picture`
4. The albums belonging to a Page, if they're public-visible `/PAGE_ID/photos`

(it seems that you want to create a dummy user, and fetch all the photos from thers, if so, point 4 could be useful to you)

Comment: so according to point 4, it's possible to get albums/photos if the albums belonged to a PAGE instead of a USER? In this case, is it also possible to get EVENTS of a page without asking for permissions?

Comment: Yes, you can fetch both photos and events of a page (if they are public). PS: you can accept the answer if helped!